# How would you call matrix of response variables?

Tags: terminology, matrix

Matrix of input variables may be called design matrix with each row to be a single datapoint and each column to be a single feature value.

How would you call matrix of response variables with each row to correspond to the same row of the design matrix and each column to be a single component of multivariate response?

(Response matrix? Output matrix?)

Comment: @FransRodenburg I ask exactly about multivariate response

Comment: I meant to say I think *multivariate response* is a fitting name for a matrix of response variables.

Comment: *Data matrix*? I suspect the name you choose is less important than clarifying in context what the rows and columns represent.

Answer (score 2):

What I know is the term *multivariate response* is appropriate when referring to such matrix. The term *output matrix* is somewhat also used, but can be ambiguous since many operations can also have a matrix as a result, yet not appropriately a response.